# We get timout error when running Invoke-RestMethod in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

***This Powershell Command :***

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST 
-ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' -Body $body
```

***Gives this error:***

---

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> 
System.Exception: Failed to execute the powershell script with error: The operation has timed out.`

**Executed Script:**

```
$SubScription = '84372afc-befd-47f0-92db-268539982d02'; 
$FeaturePackID = '1c17cf71-8438-45ee-a14a-59ebe4332c36';
$CustomerOU = 'OU=ss34(ss34),OU=Customers,DC=MANHATTAN,DC=local';
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell;
if ($SubScription -eq '') { 
    $sub = New-SPSiteSubscription; 
} else
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Any help is much Appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify the url directly in browser, to make sure its working. Or may be try using chrome REST Client to verify the url.

Comment: It is not clear what the relationship is between the Invoke-RestMethod and the executed script.  Are you passing this script in the POST body to be executed in the context of the REST service?  Also it looks like you're using a SOAP-based web service and not a RESTful web service.  For SOAP, you should consider using New-WebServiceProxy instead.  It will generate an object whose methods you can call to interact with the SOAP web service.

Comment: I will try this on monday guys, thanks you for your tips :)